# Unable to Write Zeros to Bad Sectors/Hard Disk Not Counting Reallocated Sectors

Tags: hard-drive, smart, bad-sectors, sectors

I have a drive that is reporting that the current pending sectors is "45". I have used *badblocks* to identify the sectors and I have been trying to write zeros to them with *dd*.

From what I understand, when I attempt writing data directly to the bad sectors, it should trigger a reallocation, reducing current pending sectors by one and increasing the reallocated sector count.

However, on this disk both Reallocated_Sector_Ct and Reallocated_Event_Count raw values are 0, and *dd* fails with I/O errors when I attempt to write zeros to the bad sectors. *dd* works fine, however, when I write to a good sector.

```
# dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/sdb bs=512 count=1 seek=217152
dd: error writing ‘/dev/sdb’: Input/output error
```

Does this mean that my drive, in some way, has no spare sectors to be used for reallocation? Is my drive just in general a terrible person? (The drive isn't actually mine, I'm helping a friend out. They might have just gotten a cheap drive or something.)

In case it is relevant, here is the output of *smartctl -i* :

```
Model Family:     Western Digital Caviar Green (AF)
Device Model:     WDC WD15EARS-00Z5B1
Serial Number:    WD-WMAVU3027748
LU WWN Device Id: 5 0014ee 25998d213
Firmware Version: 80.00A80
User Capacity:    1,500,301,910,016 bytes [1.50 TB]
Sector Size:      512 bytes logical/physical
Device is:        In smartctl database [for details use: -P show]
ATA Version is:   ATA8-ACS (minor revision not indicated)
SATA Version is:  SATA 2.6, 3.0 Gb/s
Local Time is:    Fri Oct 18 17:47:29 2013 CDT
SMART support is: Available - device has SMART capability.
SMART support is: Enabled
```

**UPDATE:**
I have run `shred` on the disk, which has caused Current_Pending_Sector to go to zero. However, Reallocated_Sector_Ct and Reallocated_Event_Count are still zero, and dd is now able to write data to the sectors it was previously unable to. This leads me with several other questions:

- Why aren't the reallocations being recored by the disk? I'm assuming the reallocation took place as I can now write data directly to the sector and couldn't before.
- Why did shred cause reallocation and not dd? Does the fact that shred writes random data instead of just zeros make a difference?

Comment: How are the other SMART values? Is `Uncorrectable Sector Count` more than zero?

Comment: Offline_Uncorrectable, which I'm assuming is the same thing, has a raw value of 25.

Comment: Yes it is, and it sounds like the drive is indeed in bad shape. You can check the values against [this table](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/S.M.A.R.T.#Known_ATA_S.M.A.R.T._attributes), paying special attention to the red rows (health-critical values). The best bet is to copy (not move) everything valuable/irreplaceable to somewhere else, reboot to give it a power cycle, and if it still works, give it a good wipe (preferably with its own [dedicated tools](http://support.wdc.com/product/download.asp?groupid=608&sid=3), and set it aside as spare storage for unimportant data like downloaded videos.

Comment: Thanks for your response. My main question would probably have to be why it can't reallocate those sectors. Shouldn't it just detect the sectors are bad, shun them into the void, reallocate, and move on? I'm not worried about any data on the disk as it has long been cleaned off. My friend is not eager to have a 1.5TB paperweight if they can avoid it.

Comment: That seems like the thing to expect, but it might be that it has a bad head. If so, then trying to read the drive would work until you try to access the platter that has a bad head, then you’ll get a bunch of read errors because without a head to read, the whole platter is inaccessible. Of course it says sector 45 is bad which might be because it’s already by  re-allocated but the SMART wasn’t updated. The [warranty expired](http://websupport.wdc.com/warranty/warrantycheck2.asp?req=385567&rnd=03914148) a few months ago, but you can try emailing them and maybe they’ll do a courtesy replacement.

Comment: The sector right before 217152 is readable by dd, and `badblocks` show that there are only ~7 bad sectors after it. I don't know about the whereabouts of the others as I didn't do the full scan, but that should leave at least 8 bad sectors that should be able to be reallocated, no? Also, sorry if I wasn't clear, I meant that 45 sectors were bad, not sector 45.

Comment: Ah, well it is having trouble in one or another. Have you tried simply running a disk scan to mark the bad clusters  in the file-system so that they are outright ignored? The rest of the drive should then be usable without issue (at least for now).

Comment: That what I've been trying to do. From what I've read, attempting to write zeros to the bad sector should trigger a reallocation and cause the bad sector to be ignored. The problem is that dd fails to do this, suggesting that something is failing at the reallocation process or it's just not being triggered, as both Reallocated_Sector_Ct and Reallocated_Event_Count are zero.

Comment: You’re trying to make the drive relocate the bad sector in software, what I meant was getting the file-system to flag the cluster containing it as bad in software. I don’t know about Linux, but for example, using `chkdsk /r` in Windows on a FAT32 partition will detect when a sector is inaccessible and flag the cluster containing it as `BAD` instead of `FREE` in the FAT. The sector remains bad and trying to access it will fail, but its flagged at a high-level and OS skips it altogether.

Comment: I don't have a filesystem on this drive at all. I'm writing raw zeros to the drive with dd, as many guides suggest it should. I imagine the ext4 filesystem has some high level way to deal with this, but that still doesn't do anything about the fact that my harddrive if failing to preform a rather vital function.

Comment: Exactly, the drive has a physical problem and you are not able to write to those sectors. They are dead and if you cannot write to them, then there’s nothing you can do about it but flag them. If it has no file-system, then you should be able to format it, and let the file-system mark them as bad. Then cross your fingers that it is just those few sectors that are bad, especially since the SMART data is indicating that it cannot even reallocate bad sectors. Again, try power-cycling it to see if that gives it a nudge and jiggles something loose like a deadlock in the firmware.

Comment: No dice. :/ I suppose the best I can do at this point is monitor the drive and see if I get a rapid increase in pending sector reallocations. I'll leave the question open a little longer to see if anyone else can enlighten us. :P

Comment: If all else fails, you can use it as a spare drive for unimportant stuff. That’s what I did with my old 100GB WD when it started having too many problems.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The WD15EARS drive (and most other recently produced drives) uses [Advanced Format](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Advanced_Format), which means that the real physical sector size of this drive is 4 KiB, and the traditional 512-byte sector size is just emulated. Because of this, if a single 4 KiB physical sector goes bad, all 8 corresponding emulated 512-byte sectors become unreadable at once.

(The `Sector Size:      512 bytes logical/physical` output from `smartctl` is not correct, because [some WD15EARS drives report wrong physical sector size](http://karelzak.blogspot.ru/2010/05/4096-byte-sector-hard-drives.html) — apparently your drive has a firmware version which is broken in that respect.)

Moreover, when a single emulated 512-byte sector is written, the Advanced Format drive actually needs to read the whole 4 KiB physical sector, change the corresponding 512-byte part of it, then write the whole physical sector to the media. If the media is good, this read-modify-write operation just causes a significant slowdown compared to a drive with real 512-byte physical sectors. However, if the 4 KiB physical sector is bad and cannot be read, any write operation which does not rewrite the sector completely will fail. Because of this, you cannot force sector reallocation on such drives using `dd` with `bs=512 count=1` — you must use at least `bs=512 count=8` and make sure that the sector number in the `seek=` option is a multiple of 8. (This assumes that the “Windows XP Compatible” jumper is not installed, otherwise the alignment offset added by this jumper must also be taken into account.)

Another reason why forcing the reallocation with `dd` might fail is that by default Linux uses a cache in the block layer to access block devices, and this may cause read-modify-write operations in software, which would also fail when an unreadable sector is encountered. You can add the `oflag=direct` option to bypass this cache for the device specified by `of=...` (there is also the `iflag=direct` option, which applies to the input device).

Comment: Thank you, thank you, thank you, this was so helpful. I read the label on the drive and it says "advance format". I know what that means now... Do you have any idea, though, about the drive not reporting any reallocated sectors?

Comment: "current pending sectors" are not necessarily bad sectors, the disk just had a little bit of trouble reading it before in its idle checks, possibly due to not having written there in a long time and the data starting to fade (ie magnetic field weakening). Writing new data to that sector refreshes the data in that sector with new data that is strongly formed on the disk.  Thus if you write to a pending sector the disk assumes it is ok now.  You should try reading the data back from those sectors to confirm they are stable.

Comment: for those people who don't care about any data on the disk and don't want to find the exact list of sectors or do the sector count math just dd the entire disk with a block size of a multiple of 4KiB, like 16MiB.  Then use a block size of 4KiB for the last part of the disk that is smaller than the previously chosen block size.

Answer (score 0):

I had to do this recently and found that running shred on the whole disk worked very well. While shred is useless for its intended purpose except on diskettes, it does just what is required to get the self-healing going on bad blocks.